# Why the clk_divider not working?

Tags: vhdl

The code is:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity clk_div is
Port (
         clk_in                      : in  STD_LOGIC;
         clk_out_rx              : out std_logic;
         out_bit_parity          : out std_logic
     ); 
end clk_div;
architecture Behavioral of clk_div is
signal clk_slow_tx : std_logic := '0';
signal q : unsigned(9 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin

process ( clk_in ) is 
begin 
if rising_edge(clk_in) then
q <= q + 1;
clk_slow_tx <= q(8);   --- 58.gdfg/2^8 =~ 230Khz baud rate = 115200 
clk_out_rx <= clk_slow_tx;
end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

I am adding the testbench waveform of the above code: 
If you need the testbench code I can write that also.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The output `out_bit_parity` is not assigned in the module, but the other output `clk_out_rx` toggles fine:

[image]

Test bench added below on request:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mdl_tb is
end entity;


library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

architecture sim of mdl_tb is

  constant CLK_FREQ : real := 100.0E6;  -- Clock frequency in Hz
  signal clk        : std_logic;

  signal dut_clk_out_rx     : std_logic;
  signal dut_out_bit_parity : std_logic;

begin

  process is
  begin
    while TRUE loop
      clk <= '1';
      wait for 0.5 sec / CLK_FREQ;
      clk <= '0';
      wait for (1.0 sec / CLK_FREQ) - (0.5 sec / CLK_FREQ);
    end loop;
  end process;

  mdl_e : entity work.clk_div
    port map(
      clk_in => clk,
      clk_out_rx => dut_clk_out_rx,
      out_bit_parity => dut_out_bit_parity);

end architecture;
```

Comment: can you show me the test bench ? I don't care about the out_bit_parity.

Comment: Added in answer; it is not rocket science, but hope it helps.

Comment: The questioner appears to have generated his clock by combinatorial means in his testbench.  Notice the appearance of of signal transitions in the positive baud of in both `clk` and `clk_out_rx` in his waveform image.  (Didn't use a combinatorial JK flip flop, did he?)  And the way to fix that is unbalance the feed back paths with different delays.

Comment: I got it when we create the testbench .. it generates the testbench for the two clocks..one needs to be deleted from the testbench code.